# Cómo llamar a Google Assistant desde otra aplicación hecha en Processing / android?

Tags: android, processing

necesito el comando y ruta para abrir **Google Assistant** desde un programa hecho por mí `(Processing android )`, solo eso , he probado con lo siguiente :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity")); 
startActivity(intent);
```

en el `package` coloqué lo que supongo es la ruta del `Google Assistant`, pero no me lo abre ( tampoco me da error ) simplemente no pasa nada ,por lo tanto no se que estará mal ,faltando ,o bien `Google Assistant` no permite ser abierto desde una app distinta . Gracias

**Pd : processing es como un java más resumido**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El còdigo que muestras realizarà un Intent para abrir una Activity dentro de una aplicaciòn.

Si deseas abrir Google Assistant lo correcto es realizarlo de esta forma para iniciar el comando de voz.:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge por tu respuesta , llevare a cabo tu propuesta a mi aplicación y posteriormente comentaré que tal me ha ido ! un gran abrazo !

Comment: Hola Jorgesys , te confirmo que efectivamente tu respuesta me sirvió al 100 % para mi propósito ! primer intento que hice implementando exactamente tal como me recomendaste funcionó de una mi aplicación ! Te agradezco infinitamente tu ayuda ( hace unas semanas vengo buscando y estudiando este tema ) no soy muy programador de Android  , si de otros lenguajes , y necesitaba resolver esto . Doy por finalizado el tema !